# How to set the limit time using CVXPY

Tags: python, solver, cplex, cvxpy

I 'm trying to resolve a problem using the CVXPY and I need to set up a time limit. How can I do it ?

I tried so set an argument like time_limit or maximumseconds and I didn't get no result. I read the Documentation but I didn't find none about this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to help you better, please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

The CVXPY documentation [here](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#solve-method-options) (scroll down to where it says "CPLEX options") explains how to set CPLEX parameters in CVXPY. For example, to set the [time limit](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/TiLim.html) parameter to 60 seconds, you would do the following:

```
prob.solve(solver=cvxpy.CPLEX, verbose=True, cplex_params={"timelimit": 60})
```

Comment: Worked it. Thanks.

Comment: @ThiagoCorreia: If you don't mind, please [accept one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), so that others can see that the question has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
prob.solve(solver=cvxpy.CPLEX, cplex_params={"timelimit": 20})
```

Comment: Worked it. Thanks.